# I have a weird segmentation fault, std::length_error and sometimes my code works?

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault, std

I finished some code that prints out how many times a word shows up. However, when I finished and tried to run the code on a different compiler it did not work. Firstly, here is a picture of my code working on my initial file:
[image]

But when I used a different compiler (onlinegdb) I get this error:
[image]

The thing that confused me the most is; when I try and replicate the file into a new VS Code .cpp file, it does not work. It runs the code but then prints out nothing. When I went into gdb I find this error:
[image]

If anyone knows where the segmentation fault/std::length_error are happening at please let me know, and if you have any recommendations that would be great! Also, knowing why I get different results on the same compiler (VS Code) would also be helpful. Here is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class WordOccurrence 
{
public:
    WordOccurrence(const string& word="", int num=1)
    {
        word_ = word;
        num_ = num;
    }
    bool matchWord(const string & compare)
    {
        if(word_ == compare)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }   
    void increment()             
    {
        num_++;
    }   
    string getWord() const      
    {
        return word_;
    }
    int getNum() const          
    {
        return num_;
    }
private:
    string word_;
    int num_;
};

class WordList
{
public:
    friend bool equal(const WordList&, const WordList&);
    WordList();                         
    WordList(const WordList &);         
    ~WordList();                            
    WordList operator= (const WordList &);  
    void addWordFile(WordList w);
    void addWord(const string &);
    void print();
private:
    WordOccurrence *wordArray_;         
    int size_;
};

WordList::WordList() 
{
    size_ = 0;
    wordArray_ = new WordOccurrence [size_];
}

WordList::WordList (const WordList &neww) 
{   
    size_ = neww.size_;
    wordArray_ = new WordOccurrence[size_];

    for (int i = 0; i <= (size_ - 1); i++) 
        wordArray_[i] = neww.wordArray_[i];
}

WordList::~WordList () 
{
    delete [] wordArray_;
}

WordList WordList::operator= (WordList const &overload) 
{
    WordList temp(overload);
    swap(wordArray_, temp.wordArray_);
    swap(size_, temp.size_);
    return *this;
}

void WordList::addWord(const string& word) 
{
    if(size_ == 0)
    {
        WordOccurrence *first_array = new WordOccurrence[1];
        first_array[0] = word;
        delete[] wordArray_;
        wordArray_ = first_array;
        delete[] first_array;
        size_++;
        return;
    }

//if the word is already in the array, we increase the count of it by 1
    for (int i = 0; i < size_; i++) 
    {
        if (wordArray_[i].matchWord(word)) 
        {
            wordArray_[i].increment();
            return;
        }
    }

//if it is not in the array already, we need to increase its size and then add the new word to the wordarray.
    WordOccurrence *new_array = new WordOccurrence[size_+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < size_; i++)
    {
        new_array[i] = wordArray_[i];
    }
    new_array[size_] = WordOccurrence(word); 
    delete[] wordArray_;
    size_++;
    wordArray_ = new_array;
    delete[] new_array;
}
void WordList::print() 
{
//to output to a file because when we get a lot of words it's kinda hard to see on just the terminal
    ofstream myfile ("output.txt");
    WordList sortedList(*this);
    
//Sorting from smallest to largest
    int smallest = wordArray_[0].getNum();

    for (int i = 1; i < size_; i++) 
    {
//stores the smallest value into smallest
        if(wordArray_[i].getNum() < smallest) 
            smallest = wordArray_[i].getNum();
    }
    int location = 0;
//stores values from start to finish in the new list starting at location sortedList[0]
    while(location < size_) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < size_; i++) 
        {
//runs through the new list until it finds a value that is apart of the smallest/rarest words
            if(wordArray_[i].getNum() == smallest) 
            {
                sortedList.wordArray_[location] = wordArray_[i];
                location++;
            }
        }
//increases the value of smallest allowing for numbers with greater found values to be sorted
        smallest++;
    }   
//prints out the sorted version of wordarray
    for(int i = 0; i < size_; i++) 
    {
        string word = sortedList.wordArray_[i].getWord();
        int count = sortedList.wordArray_[i].getNum();
        cout << "Word: " << word << "   Amount: " << count << endl;
        //for longer amounts of text, it was hard to see on a editor so I also have it out to a file.
        myfile << "Word: " << word << "   Amount: " << count << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    WordList w;
    w.addWord("one");
    w.addWord("one"); 
    w.addWord("two");
    w.addWord("three");
    w.addWord("four");
    w.addWord("four");
    w.addWord("four");
    w.addWord("four");
    w.addWord("five");
    w.addWord("five");
    w.addWord("five");

    cout << "Sorted list" << endl;
    w.print();
}
```

Comment: You should use `std::vector` (or another container fitting your needs) rather than trying to juggle raw dynamic allocations. I see several places where you store a pointer to a newly allocated array, only to immediately `delete` it.

Comment: `delete[] first_array;` is wrong if you think about it. Same with `delete[] new_array;`

Comment: Other comments - you should return a reference from your assignment operator.

Comment: This was a lab for my class and it says the use of vector is not allowed. We were given a prototype class to use and we had to write the code for it.

Comment: Use std::map<>.

Answer (score 1):

This is bugged

```
    WordOccurrence *first_array = new WordOccurrence[1];
    first_array[0] = word;
    delete[] wordArray_;
    wordArray_ = first_array;
    delete[] first_array;
    size_++;
    return;
```

You assign `first_array` to `wordArray_` and then you delete it. This leaves `wordArray_` as an invalid pointer. Just remove `delete[] first_array;`. Two deletes and only one new should have been a clue that something was wrong.

Same bug later on in the same function

```
WordOccurrence *new_array = new WordOccurrence[size_+1];
for (int i = 0; i < size_; i++)
{
    new_array[i] = wordArray_[i];
}
new_array[size_] = WordOccurrence(word); 
delete[] wordArray_;
size_++;
wordArray_ = new_array;
delete[] new_array;
```

`delete[] new_array;` should not be there.

Comment: This seems to be my problem! I never really have used delete[] before and never thought of it this way. It definitely makes sense now that I think about it though.